# How do I edit the Contacts page through the Developer console?

Tags: contact, developer-console, code

I'm a complete novice when it comes to the Developer Console, and coding in general.

I'd like to change the width and height of a field on the Contacts page (it's a formula text field), but so far, I haven't been able to access any code through the Console. I can only see the field I want to resize as a read-only "string" Apex type on Contact.obj.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. Formula fields always take exactly as much space as they need, and no more.

Comment: But how do I access the code of the Contacts page?

Comment: @ESil You can only access code you've created yourself. Unless you're willing to take the time to write an entire Visualforce page just to enhance this one field, there's nothing you can do. There's no configuration-based method for changing a field's size.